# jQuery apply class to <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-datepicker

My current **`HTML`** structure

```
<div class="pull-right" id="sandbox-container">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-inline">
<div class="datepicker-days">
<table class=" table-condensed"><thead>
<tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th>
<th class="datepicker-switch" colspan="5">October 2014</th>
<th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th></tr>
<tr>
<th class="dow">Mo</th>
<th class="dow">Tu</th>
<th class="dow">We</th>
<th class="dow">Th</th>
<th class="dow">Fr</th>
<th class="dow">Sa</th>
<th class="dow">Su</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="old day">29</td>
<td class="old day">30</td>
<td class="day">1</td>
<td class="day">2</td>
<td class="day">3</td>
<td class="disabled day">4</td>
<td class="disabled day">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="day">6</td>
<td class="day">7</td>
<td class="day">8</td>
<td class="day">9</td>
<td class="day">10</td>
<td class="disabled day">11</td>
<td class="disabled day">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="day">13</td>
<td class="day">14</td>
<td class="day">15</td>
<td class="day">16</td>
<td class="day">17</td>
<td class="disabled day">18</td>
<td class="disabled day">19</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="day">20</td>
<td class="day">21</td>
<td class="day">22</td>
<td class="day">23</td>
<td class="day">24</td>
<td class="disabled day">25</td>
<td class="disabled day">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="day">27</td>
<td class="day">28</td>
<td class="today day">29</td>
<td class="day">30</td>
<td class="day">31</td>
<td class="new disabled day">1</td>
<td class="new disabled day">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="new day">3</td>
<td class="new day">4</td>
<td class="new day">5</td>
<td class="new day">6</td>
<td class="new day">7</td>
<td class="new disabled day">8</td>
<td class="new disabled day">9</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th class="today" colspan="7" style="display: none;">Today</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="clear" colspan="7" style="display: none;">Clear</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>  
</div>  
</div>
```

In the above generated `HTML`, there is one `<td>` with class `today day` which is

```
<tr>
    <td class="day">27</td>
    <td class="day">28</td>
    <td class="today day">29</td>
    <td class="day">30</td>
    <td class="day">31</td>
    <td class="new disabled day">1</td>
    <td class="new disabled day">2</td>
</tr>
```

How can I apply CSS class to its `<tr>`, so the result would be

```
<tr class="mycustomClass">
    <td class="day">27</td>
    <td class="day">28</td>
    <td class="today day">29</td>
    <td class="day">30</td>
    <td class="day">31</td>
    <td class="new disabled day">1</td>
    <td class="new disabled day">2</td>
</tr>
```

The class `today day` will be applied to only one `<td>`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : find `td` having class="today day" and get the parent of it to add `mycustomClass`

```
$(function(){
  $('td.today.day').parent().addClass('mycustomClass');
});
```

Comment: Why is the class `td.today.day` and not `td.today day` ?

Comment: `td.today.day` will find `td` having both clasess and `td.today day` this will try to find `td` with class `today` and then it will find child of that `td` which is having `day` class, I mean this will find children of `td` with `class="day"`. Here space denotes find child(right side) of parent(left side).

Comment: It is selector to find descendant (not parent child), For more information see [Decendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the `td` with classes `today` and `day` then find its parent which will be the `tr` element and add the class `mycustomclass` to it.

```
$('td.today.day').parent().addClass('mycustomClass')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".today.day").closest("tr").addClass("mycustomClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent TR element of the TD with classes "today" and "day" and add class to it using addClass().

You can try the following,

```
$('td.today.day').parent('tr').addClass('YourClass')
```

Comment: Include some explanation as to what your posted code does to solve the issue.